# Text and Link sharing by share_open_graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, fb.ui

I am getting issue with FB share_open_graph API. I have some text on a page and have one button to share that text and page URL (http://www.example.com?article_id=123).

Clicking share button text and link get share on Facebook users wall. But if user click the post from Facebook wall then link is got update with new parameters "fb_action_ids and fb_action_types".
Updated URL: http://www.example.com?article_id=123&fb_action_ids=422174444504370&fb_action_types=og.shares

Now if user wants to share again those text and page link FB share_open_graph API throws errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0U3W.png)

```
FB.ui({
method: 'share_open_graph',
action_type: 'og.shares',
action_properties: JSON.stringify({
    object : {
        'og:url': url, // your url to share
        'og:title': title,
        'og:description': desc
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to share the second URL in the second instance then? Don’t do that, share your original one.

Comment: But on that time I dont have original URL. I am working on a wirget type component that have FB share functionality.

Comment: Then get it somehow. Does your page not have a canonical meta tag or something that you could read it from? Otherwise you’ll end up sharing _different_ URLs, which will mean like and share count will also be split among those.

Comment: It is a 3rd party widget on which i work and thousands of sites uses this on which I don’t have control. So I have to read URLs on runtime only.

Comment: Well I guess you could have your script look for those two specific query string parameters in the URL, and remove them ...

Comment: Is there any configuration available in FB API to prevent from adding extra parameters on URL?

Comment: No, there isn’t.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I will try to get removed these by my code. :)